# How to fix deleted task being restored in Userdefaultrs

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm making a TodoList app.
If you swipe a task from the list to delete it and then add a new task, the deleted task will be restored.
Use storyboard and UIKit.
I want to keep it deleted, what should I do? ..

mac 10.15.7
xcode 12.1

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var tasks = [String]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "リスト"
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        if !UserDefaults().bool(forKey: "setup") {
            UserDefaults().set(true, forKey: "setup")
            UserDefaults().set(0, forKey: "count")
        }
        updateTasks()
    }
    
    func updateTasks() {
        
        tasks.removeAll()
        
        guard let count = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "count") as? Int else {
            return
        }
        
        for x in 0..<count {

            if let task = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "task_\(x+1)") as? String {
                tasks.append(task)
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapAdd() {
        
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "entry") as! EntryViewController
        vc.title = "リストに追加"
        vc.update = {
            //非同期処理　更新を優先
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updateTasks()
            }
        }
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "task") as! TaskViewController
        vc.title = "リストに追加"
        vc.task = tasks[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasks.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = tasks[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    //タスクを削除
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let index = indexPath.row
        tasks.remove(at: index)
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.set(tasks, forKey: "tasks")
        userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: "tasks")
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Is remove (at :) different?

```
import UIKit

class EntryViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var field: UITextField!
    var update: (() -> Void)?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        field.delegate = self
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "保存", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(saveTask))
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        saveTask()
        return true
    }
    
    @objc func saveTask() {
        guard let text = field.text, !text.isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        guard let count = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "count") as? Int else {
            return
        }
        let newCount = count + 1
        UserDefaults().set(newCount, forKey: "count")
        UserDefaults().set(text, forKey: "task_\(newCount)")
        update?()
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

How to save UserDefaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see is; in **updateTasks** function, you get the tasks from UserDefaults by keys as task_1, task_2 etc. But when deleting a specific task, lets say task_2, you are just removing it from tasks array, not deleting it from UserDefaults. So whenever you call **updateTasks** function, the deleted task re-appears.

In your EntryViewController, change the saveTask function with following:

```
@objc func saveTask() {
    guard let text = field.text, !text.isEmpty else {
        return
    }

    let tasks = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "tasks") as? [String] ?? []
    tasks.append(text)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(tasks, forKey: "tasks")
    update?()
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

In your ViewController, change the following functions:

```
func updateTasks() {
    
    tasks.removeAll()
    
    tasks = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "tasks") as? [String] ?? []
    
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.set(tasks, forKey: "tasks")
    updateTasks()
}
```